# Avaya IP Office TAPI Driver only show first extension

Tags: telephony, tapi, avaya

I have taken over a CTI project for the Avaya IP Office PBX and am trying to resolve a customer issue for a new installation on site which I also have on my test system in the office. Our CTI application uses the Avaya TAPI driver to communicate with the PBX, I have configured the TAPI driver with the IP address of the PBX, enabled third party mode (I need to see data from all extensions), enabled ACD queues and entered the correct password. I've also turned on debug tracing in the driver. I am using Astice TAPI monitor to check that everything is okay before turning on our application but here is where the problem lies: In Windows only the first extension configured on the switch is displaying in Windows, everything works correctly for this extension and I see call details fine but it does not display any other extensions and this is the exact problem that I have on the customer site.

On my test system, IP Office itself seems to be configured correctly (AFAIK there is not much config to do on the PBX anyway) and the CTI Link Pro license is enabled and displayed as valid and set to never expire.

Does anybody have any idea at all why only the first extension should be displayed?

EDIT: I've since found that this issue only occurs on Windows 7, on Windows XP it is fine. This means that it is highly unlikely that the problem is due to any settings on the PBX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the (unlikely) case that anybody else has had this issue it was actually due to the Avaya TAPI driver not supporting Windows 7. I procured a newer driver from Avaya which resolved the issue. These drivers are not generally available so you will need a support or partnership contract with Avaya. Presumably if you are looking at a similar issue then that won't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was trying use password "Administrator" for third-party, and there was one extension in "phone.exe" named "Line unnamed", problem was in password: default is "password".